# How to make changes in navigation bar when a user gets logged in?

Tags: laravel, authentication, vue.js, navigation, jwt

I am using **Laravel** with **vue** and using **JWT auth** for authentication. I have made a navigation bar and I want to change the links of that bar to change to different one's when the user gets logged-in. I have stored the token of jwt to local storage but I am unable to make the links work. Please help as I am new to these technologies.

I have tried implementing it with *Event Bus* and was able to change the links but when I click the logout button it does not remove the *token* item from *local storage* and does not invoke the function also. I guess there is some problem with code logic but I am unable to figure that out.

Navigation bar

```
    <nav class="main_nav">
          <input type="checkbox" id="nav_check" class="hidden">
          <label for="nav_check" class="nav-btn">
            <i></i>
          </label>
          <div class="logo">
            <a href="#">SCRIPTICO</a>
          </div>
          <div class="nav-wrapper">
            <ul>
              <li v-if="auth == ''">
                <router-link to="/login">Sign in</router-link>
              </li>
              <li v-if="auth ==''">
                <router-link to="/register">Register</router-link>
              </li>
              <li v-if="auth !==''">
                <router-link to="/userdetails">Dashboard</router-link>
              </li>
              <li v-if="auth !==''">
                <router-link to="/" v-on:click="handleLogout()">Logout</router-link>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>
```

This is what I tried

```
<script>
import EventBus from './EventBus'
export default {
    data(){
      return{
        auth: '',
        user: ''
      }
    },

    methods:{
        handleLogout() {
        console.log('this is it')
      window.localStorage.removeItem("usertoken");
      this.$router.push({ path: "/" });
    }
    },
    mounted(){
      EventBus.$on('logged-in', status => {
        this.auth = status
        console.log(status)
      })
    }
}
</script>
```

Event bus vue file

```
<script>
import Vue from 'vue'
const EventBus = new Vue()
export default EventBus
</script>
```

what I am expecting from the behavior is when the user is not logged in the navbar should show the links for Register and login and when the user gets logged in the links should change to logout only.

Comment: on logout use `localStorage.clear();` then hit your event bus `EventBus.$emit('refresh');`

Comment: @KaranSadana I tried that but the problem is the method is not getting invoked, I mean the console is also not showing up.

Comment: i just check this out. giving click to `router link` not work try to do it in `<a>` tag or some ` <button v-on:click="logout()">logout</button>`

Comment: @KaranSadana Thank You ! it worked with <a> tag but now the links after getting logged out are not changing.

Comment: because you doing router push 
and eventbus work only on same page , so when you redirecting its a diffrenet page.

Comment: @KaranSadana So I need to move the EventBus to home page?

Comment: i suggest you to do this code in mouted method of nav component like , chcek user is logged in `if(localStorage.getItem('AccessKey') != null){ this.log = true;}` and do v-if in links router

Comment: `<li v-if="log">login</li>` and in logout use `<a v-if='!log'>logout</a>`

Comment: No problem keep learning :)

Comment: @KaranSadana Hey, I am really thankful for your help before but there is one more problem with this code. When I implemented the button on nav shows right according to user auth but when the token from local storage changes the buttons does not...I mean the button which is showing in nav stays there and does not appear or disappear, Please help.

Comment: its simply checking , if token not present means user is logged out and you need to show login button and if token is present means user is logged in and you need to show logout button check here 
https://codeshare.io/5P0yRY

Comment: @KaranSadana Thank you so much again! now it is working properly..maybe I haven't passed the data before that is why it was not working...but it is now!..a big thank you :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method is not working beacuse you give click event to

`<router-link`

try to give this event to some `<button>` or `<a>`

like below

`<a href="javascript:void(0);" v-on:click='handleLogout()'>Logout<a>`
or some button

`<button v-on:click="handleLogout()">Logout<button>`

Hope it's help